# UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata returns null

Tags: ios, null

For some reason this is outputting 'null'.  The code seems to be right according to what everyone else has been saying about MediaMetaData, but unlike them, all i get out is the null?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

NSDictionary *metadata = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];

NSLog(@"%@", metadata);

}
```

Edit: I'm using a UIImagePickerController, which gets the image from the iPhone simulator's PhotoLibrary.

Also I'm using iOS 4.3

When I use NSLog(@"%@", info); that outputs:

> UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
>
> UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage =
>   "";
>
> UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL =
>   "assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=1000000001&ext=PNG";

I've tried different pictures, different filetypes.  No change.

Comment: Where are you getting the media from?

Comment: Just a UIImagePickerController, which gets it from the iPhone simulator's PhotoLibrary.

Comment: Maybe those pictures have no metadata?

Comment: I wish that was the case, but when I use the technique at  http://blog.codecropper.com/2011/05/getting-metadata-from-images-on-ios/, I get metadata output.  One of the images I tried is a sample from http://www.exif.org/ also.

Comment: Matt: It's weird, isn't it? Why offer UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata if it never seems to be present when using the camera source type? Agreed, if I dip into the asset (asynchronously), I eventually get the metadata I seek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excerpt for [`UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata) from the documentation,

> This key is valid only when using an
>   image picker whose source type is set
>   to
>   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera,
>   and applies only to still images.

You will have to use the **Asset Library** for this. Specifically build an `ALAsset` instance and access the [`metadata`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetRepresentation/metadata) property of its [`defaultRepresentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAsset/defaultRepresentation).

Comment: Ah, thanks.  It seemed like the Asset Library method gave less data than this method (in examples I saw), so I'll have to get the Filename, Date, FileSize, and FileType another way.